# Как с использованием XPath вытащить из xml разные данные за один запрос?

Tags: xpath, xml, php, yii

Доброго времени суток, знатоки! Попробую вкратце объяснить суть проблемы. У меня есть xml файл такого формата:

```
<Cnt id="681">
   <CFiles>
      <CFile name="24801"  id="24801"></CFile>
   </CFiles>
   <Pfiles>
      <PFile name="1851" id="1851"></PFile>
   </Pfiles>
</cnt>
```

И таких ячеек <cnt> у меня очень много. Также у меня есть набор id для cnt. Моя задача вытащить id и name у CFile и PFile у тех cnt, id которых мне дали. Я использую simpleXml и XPath. Запрос такого вида:

```
$model_q = $model->xpath('/Cnt[@id = '.$q.']/Pfiles/PFile');
        foreach($model_q as $mod)
        {
                $contents = Content::model()->findByAttributes(array('content_name'=>$mod['name']));
                if(!$contents)
                {
                    $content = new Content;
                    $content->content_id = $mod['id'];
                    $content->content_name = $mod['name'];
                    $content->save();
                }
        }
```

Где $q - один из id для cnt. Запрос работает, как надо, но это только PFile. А мне нужно в этом же запросе вытащить id и name для CFile. Еще один цикл писать не вариант. Как можно за один запрос вытащить данные из PFile и CFile?

Comment: В вашем xml одному cnt соответствуют N штук cfile и M штук pfile. Как вы себе это представляете в одном запросе?

Comment: Количество CFile и PFile одинаково. И в каждом cnt их по одной штуке. А вот самих cnt очень много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
/Cnt[@id='.$q.']/CFiles/CFile | /Cnt[@id='.$q.']/Pfiles/PFile
```

Comment: [Тут](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) можно потестить XPath...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я об этом способе сразу подумал, но есть один нюанс. Допустим `$model_q = $model->xpath('/Cnt[@id='.$q.']/CFiles/CFile | /Cnt[@id='.$q.']/Pfiles/PFile');` . Но мне за одну итерацию нужно вытащить id и name у `CFile` и `PFile`. А как ? Получается, что `$content->content_id = $model_q['id'];  $content->content_name = $model_q['name'];`  Но еще нужно `$content->CFile_id = $model_q['id'];`  и `$content->CFile_name = $model_q['name'];` Как можно обратится ко второй группе id и name ?

Comment: @тигрище, за одну итерацию естественно не получится. Можно как-то так (псевдокод):

    foreach($model_q as $mod){
      if($mod.nodeName=="CFile") $content->CFile_id = $mod['id'];
      if($mod.nodeName=="PFile") $content->content_id = $mod['id'];
    }

Comment: Если я все понял правильно, то проблема все равно остается. Загвоздка именно в `$mod['id']`. Получается, что он все равно в одну итерацию или PFile запишет, или CFile. А мне нужно и то, и другое в одну итерацию. Была бы возможность в `$mod['id']` как-то указать, что это атрибут именно CFile, к примеру.

Comment: @тигрище, вы сейчас на каждой итерации создаете и заполняете `$content`, а вы сделайте наоборот для заполнения `$content`'а запустите цикл, где на каждой итерации вы будете заполнять одно из свойств `$content`'а. т.е. вот цикл из комментария выше, он идет после `$content = new Content;` и до `$content->save();`. В общем тут сложно что-то советовать, не зная какая у вас полная задача и код. Попробуйте модифицировать как-то алгоритм под то, что у вас будет несколько итераций.

Comment: Все все, теперь я вас понял! ))) Точно! Я так долго сидел и не подумал об этом... эх-х-х. Спасибо огромное за помощь! )

Answer (score 0):

[[@тигрище](/users/22576/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5)](/users/22576/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5), может, для вашей задачи подойдет [simplexml_load_string()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-string.php)?

[Вот примерчик](http://ideone.com/dCjcKP).

Comment: К сожалению, не подходит, так как я работаю с файлом xml больших размеров. Но все равно спасибо. )

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб и без всякого дополнительного смысла, то можно так:

```
xpath('/Cnt[@id = '.$q.']/Pfiles/PFile, /Cnt[@id = '.$q.']/Cfiles/CFile');
```